# Machine Learning Datasets - Negative vs Positive Vocabulary Dataset

Tags: regex, machine-learning, nlp

I'm looking for a way to develop a ML dataset which compares positive vs negative vocabulary. For example "is valid" vs "not valid" or "can be used" vs "can't be used" or "not on Thursdays" vs "on Thursdays" would be the positive vs negative. It can be simplified by determining if the adverb is positive or negative. I was wondering if there are any available datasets for this or any existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some *sentiment dictionaries* you can use.

> Automated sentiment analysis is an application of text analytics
>   techniques for the identification of subjective opinions in text data.
>   It normally involves the classification of text into categories such
>   as “positive”, “negative” and in some cases “neutral” [[Source](http://provalisresearch.com/products/content-analysis-software/wordstat-dictionary/sentiment-dictionaries/)]

[WordStat Sentiment Dictionary 1.2](http://provalisresearch.com/Download/WSD.zip)

[Loughran and McDonald Financial Sentiment Dictionary](http://www.nd.edu/~mcdonald/Word_Lists.html)

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataset

Search for the articles having debate about some point. There, you will get most of positive and negative sentences. In starting, pick small paragraphs. Check efficiency of your algorithm manually.

Solution

Start with very basic approach. Like search for keyword, "not". then go for combined "can't" "wont" etc. Then check if you miss anything.

Now you can go for more sophisticated approach. Like the sentence "I took precautions with equipment, It won't harm me." It gives a positive sense. Thing you should look for is **"won't harm"**. You see, won't is negative word and harm is also a negative word. Combining both gives positive effect.